# Array still repeat or duplicate on each category on PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've code, data on table has success display, but my problem on array.. i explain here, may you know solution for my code . thanks for help

```
//this code for get kategori 
$arr=array();
$qs=mysql_query("select * from kt_barang",$con);
while($s=mysql_fetch_array($qs)){
        $arr=$s['kd_kategori'];
}


$n = 0;
$c = count($arr);
while ($n < $c) {
   $a = $arr[$n];
?>
<table border="1">
<?php

$q=mysql_query("select * from t_barang where kategori='$a'",$con);

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td style="width:30px;text-align:center;">'.$a.'</td>';  
echo '</tr>';

while($h=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    $kd=$h['kd_barang'];
    $barang[]=array($h['kd_barang']);
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td style="width:30px;text-align:center;">'.$kd.'</td>';  
    echo '</tr>';
}
print_r($barang);

$n++;
}
?>
</table>
```

output now

```
//this output array $barang
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 089686048704 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 089686060027 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 089686060065 ) 

//this output the table 
---------------------
kategori 66 
089686048704    
089686060027    
089686060065    
-----------------------
//this output array $barang still repeat from kategori 66
//This is the problem
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 089686048704 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 089686060027 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 089686060065 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 8996001524015 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 8996001524039 ) [5] => Array ( [0] => 8996001524060 ) 
----------------------
kategori 67 
089686010015    
089686010046    
089686010077    
----------------------------
```

i want to second array no repeat.

```
//this output array $barang
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 089686048704 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 089686060027 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 089686060065 ) )

//this output the table 
---------------------
kategori 66 
089686048704    
089686060027    
089686060065    
-----------------------

//this output array $barang
Array  ([3] => Array ( [0] => 8996001524015 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 8996001524039 ) [5] => Array ( [0] => 8996001524060 ) )
----------------------
kategori 67 
089686010015    
089686010046    
089686010077    
----------------------------
```

how to make array like that from my code
Thanks for your solution..

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: output array from next kategori still repeat or duplicate (the example on kategori 67 still repeat) whereas output on table no repeat .. @TobyAllen

Comment: do you know @TobyAllen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the variable `$barang` before using it:

```
$barang = array(); // <-- add this

while($h=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    $kd=$h['kd_barang'];
    $barang[]=array($h['kd_barang']);
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td style="width:30px;text-align:center;">'.$kd.'</td>';  
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

It is good practise to always set a variable to an defined state.